# opt-out of pension scheme(EPS) in EPF while changing jobs in India

Tags: india, pension, epf

I have recently changed my job.
In the previous job, my employer was making a contribution to the EPS as well, there was no option to opt-out of the pension scheme.
But in the new organisation, there is an option to opt-out of the pension scheme.

When I asked in the office, they said, if you were contributing to pension earlier, you cannot opt-out of it now.

When I checked on the internet, there were few websites, which mentioned, that while changing jobs only EPF account gets transferred and not the EPS. And if my total service is less than 10 years, I can withdraw the amount accumulated and close it.

I want to know if it is possible to opt-out of EPS while changing jobs?
I have been working only for two years, and have not completed the 10-year of my service.

P.S. - I don't want to opt-out of EPF. I want to keep contributing to EPF, but not to EPS.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPF and EPS are linked. Some organizations only provide EPS. If organizations participate in EPF, it's mandatory for EPS. So you can't selectively opt out. You can cash out the EPS when transfer of jobs if your are not joining any job.